# java file works in cmd but when renamed with .jar extension returns an error

Tags: java, file-extension

I started programming in Java a few days ago when I found out this odd thing, if I code a Java file and keep it's extension as `.java`, then the file works in cmd by typing `start java.java`. However, when I rename the file to a .jar extension and run in cmd, it can't load the file. Double clicking it says corrupt file. I don't use IntelliJ or Eclipse, I use Sublime text editor for writing the code and I execute it in cmd. Does anyone know why this happens? I have tried to build the code by using ctrl+b shortcut in Sublime, though it did not work. What to do?

Trying to run a java file in cmd after renaming it to .jar extension gives this error:

```
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx256M
Error: Could not find or load main class testing.jar
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: testing.jar
```

Comment: A JAR is a zip archive with java `.class` files (compiled `.java` files). So only renaming a source code file from `.java` to `.jar` is not going to work, you need to compile the `.java` file and then zip it up using the `jar` tool (with an appropriate manifest to make it executable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just change a file's extension and think then it will work. Starting the `.java` file via cmd is different than when you double click on it as a `.jar` file. To get a valid java archive you need to bundle it to one using your IDE or a CLI Tool.

Comment: can u tell me about a proper tool which will work?

Answer (score -1):

take a look [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-create-jar#1-using-the-defaults).
you should invoke javac to compile your java file and then create a jar with the jar command on the generated .class file